# How can I have a repeating activity in a case standard timeline?

Tags: civicase, activities

I am currently exploring CiviCase. I like to setup an activity that tracks the progress of the client every 6 months. Is this possible with a case standard timeline? I can't predict how many times this tracking activity should be entered, until the case is closed. I'm thinking of adding the timeline:

Open Case
Tracking Activity #1 (6 months)
Tracking Activity #2 (12 months)
...

Can I have the Tracking Activity #2 appear only after the Tracking Activity #1 is completed? Is this where the Reference Onset comes into play?

Comment: I comment this question as it looks to me as this scenario is not working anymore after updating from 4.7 to 5.1. If in timeline I put two or more activities of same type with reference to the same type, offset 7 (one every week) and select Newest the result is that all activities are put 7 days after the first. That was not the way it worked before!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a set up as attached and it works for me with 4.7[image]

Comment: That is very odd. I just tried a brand new install of CiviCRM 4.7.18 on Drupal and I cannot use the reference field. The dropdown is blank.

Comment: I assume you actually have added activity types to the case type configuration?

Comment: @Kiristine are you on Mattermost? https://civicrm.org/blog/michael-mcandrew/chat-infrastructure-for-civicrm

Comment: Thanks, ErikH! I filed a bug after testing this out on the demo sites.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20478

Answer (score 0):

I have done this once but it is a long time ago :-) As far as I know it is possible, and you have to set up the activity in the timeline. Just checked, the client in question solved it by having 'follow up 1', 'follow up 2' etc as activities and planning each one for a set period after the previous one. Does that help?

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. In this case, wouldn't all your follow up activities  (perhaps 1-XX) generate all at once? There's no way to only show Follow Activity #2 only once Activity #1 is completed?

Comment: Strange, but "Reference" dropdown doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.18 on Drupal